# Do orcs get paid?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

Do orcs get paid at all? Saruman employed "tens of thousands" of orcs to assault Helm's Deep. Mordor has a ton too. We can see throughout Tolkien's books that orcs covet things, which would in my mind create a desire for money, or at least some compensation. I also realize that orcs are a very convenient evil that our heroes must fight and Tolkien fantasy is rather straightforward with good and evil, so there may not be any desire in orc's heart but to kill men. However, Tolkien being the thorough world builder he is, I suspect he may have written about it or mentioned it somewhere.

So, does Tolkien provide any evidence for how orcs might be compensated for their duties, if at all?

Comment: Related: [Are there businesses in Mordor?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/89594/21267).

Comment: in fact, the related question basically asserts "orcs get paid" but doesn't really cite a reference for it...

Comment: I think *man-flesh* is the currency of the realm.

Comment: well the actual question should be - "Do Orc-Wives and Orc-Kids get pension after Orcs die"... cuz in all the scenarios the Orcs / Uruks turn out to be cannon-fodder for elves/dwarves/rohirrim/ents/eagles (basically any good guy)...

Comment: It would appear that they got to keep spoils of defeated enemies, looking at The Return of the King: "It was Gorbag started it, trying to pinch that pretty shirt."

Comment: I think @MajorStackings and I lean in the same direction.  I think they work for food.  Both the words of Saruman and the works of the Uruk-hai toward Merry and Pippin suggest that they have nearly no possessions and live at subsistence.  Remember - they are a corruption/breaking of a good species (half-elf in the case of the Uruk-hai) and evil cannot create so their motivations have to be clearly derived from the source.

Comment: Keep in mind that even in the real world, soldiers haven't always been paid. For what it's worth, Sauron was also a god-king who had some control of their wills.

Comment: Yes.  It's explicitly stated in the scene at the end of TTT, where Sam overhears the two Orc captains discussing what to do with Frodo.  Don't have the exact quote handy, but one says that the other will slip off and get all the pay and praise in Lugburz.  So at least the upper echelons of the orc hierarchy got paid, though at least some at the lowest levels were 'snaga' - slaves.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield - I asked that question and I cited my source in the comments.  I cite the same source in my answer to this question.

Comment: @Shamshiel - they may or may not not have received a steady paycheck, but they did, at the very least, receive financial rewards for successfully completing certain tasks - while carrying Merry and Pippin, one Orc accuses another of trying to "get all the pay and praise in Lugburz".

Comment: Thinking on this, there seems to be a lack of any description of economics in most of LOTR.  After the hobbits leave Bree, I don't recall any mention of money or trade.  Elrond supports them at Rivendell, and provides provisions for the first stage of the journey; Galadriel resupplies them for the second, then they get provisions from various militaries.  Merry & Pippin are guests of Treebeard, then do a bit of looting after the attack on Isengard...

Comment: @jamesqf I don't think I recall any money in the trilogy, but there's certainly mention of it in The Hobbit. There's even a legally binding contract in the beginning between the 12 dwarves and bilbo. There's also the giant hoard of gold underneath Smaug. In fact, Tolkien seems to go more in-depth with the hobbit than I remember in the trilogy. He gives you the whole history of Dale, Laketown, the dwarven city (erebor?), and the evlen city as well, and how they interact with each-other economically

Comment: @Tom Sterkenburg: That's pretty much exactly what I meant.  The Hobbit has a good bit of money/economics in it, but LOTR doesn't IIRC have any after the hobbits get compensated for their stolen ponies, and buy Sam's pony, in Bree.  When they're not travelling (or captives), they're guests of nobles or semi-mythical beings.  (Must be nice!  Sure beats staying in a B&B or hostel.)  So not only do we not know much about the economy of Mordor, the same can be said for Rohan and Gondor.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes - not necessarily a regular paycheck, but they get financial incentives for good performance.

When Merry and Pippin are captives, the Orcs argue about what to do with them. One Orc from Mordor suggests bringing the hobbits to a winged Nazgul nearby, and another Orc, from Isengard, gets suspicious, and says:

> "Maybe! Then you'll fly off with our prisoners, and get all the **pay** and praise in Lugburz..."
>   -*The Lord of the Rings, The Two Towers, Book III, Chapter 3: "The Uruk-Hai"*

"Lugburz" is Barad-Dur, also known as the Dark Tower, also known as the Tower of Sauron - the big black thing with the fiery eye on top in the movies.  The implication is obviously that Sauron pays his servants for a job well done.

I have no idea what Orcs would do with the money they earn - the answers to [my question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89594/are-there-businesses-in-mordor) about whether there are businesses in Mordor seem to suggest that there is no evidence of any businesses, and outside Mordor, Orcs tend to take whatever they want without paying for it;  money is useless if you have nowhere to spend it.

But clearly, this passage makes it plain to see that Orcs do get financial incentives for doing important tasks, and they obviously appreciate these incentives for some reason.

We also learn that, generally speaking, Orcs are fond of objects of value.  Just after Sam and Frodo enter Mordor, Frodo has his fateful encounter with Shelob's, and is carried off, unconscious, by Orcs.  While trying to rescue his master, Sam overhears two Orc captains, Shagrat and Gorbag, expressing their displeasure with Sauron's regime.

> "I’d like to try somewhere where there’s none of ’em ["'em" refers to Shelob, the Nazgul, Sauron, and other "bosses"]. But the war’s on now, and when that’s over things may be easier."
>   "It’s going well, they say."
>   "They would. grunted Gorbag. We’ll see. But anyway, if it does go well, there should be a lot more room. **What d’you say?-if we get a chance, you and me’ll slip off and set up somewhere on our own with a few trusty lads, somewhere where there’s good loot nice and handy, and no big bosses.**"
>   "Ah! said Shagrat, "Like old times."
>   -*The Lord of the Rings, The Two Towers, Book IV, Chapter 10: "The Choices of Master Samwise"*

So, left to their own devices, Orcs are inclined to make their living by stealing, looting, plundering, and the like;  they also resent being subordinate to other authorities, especially when things go badly for said authorities.  Before Shagrat and Gorbag came into Sauron's employ, they used to steal themselves a living, and in their idle moments under Sauron's regime, they dreamed of returning to their old ways, free from the interference of higher authorities.  It is also worth noting that these two old friends end up killing each other shortly after this conversation takes place, or at least trying to do so.

It appears that Orcs crave riches, but are inherently prone to infighting and discord.  Sauron seems to have taken advantage of these traits by maintaining order through a combination of offering incentives for good conduct and instilling the fear of horrific punishments for those who defy his will.

---

*Note:  As Shamshiel points out in his own answer, from an Orc's perspective, being paid too much is not necessarily a good thing, if there are other Orcs around.  Orcs tend to use any excuse they can find to kill each other (at one point, an Orc is tired and kills another Orc who won't let him go to bed), so getting lots of nice stuff would probably mean you are going to be murdered and robbed in the very near future.*

Comment: Perhaps not monetary gain, but rewards in the ways of things and food?

Comment: @TomSterkenburg - Not food- we read elsewhere that provisions are brought in by wagons and presumably distributed to everyone.  On a practical level, it would have to work this way, since soldiers and slaves who have starved to death are useless.  It may be things - items of value, but not actual money - but the things would have to be valuable, or no one would care whether or not they got those things.

Comment: So Tolkien doesn't explicitly mention the inner workings on the orc army economy, I'm guessing

Comment: @TomSterkenburg - I'm almost done reading the third and final book of the LotR trilogy, and so far I haven't come across much along those lines.  All I know is that it involves lots of whipping and occasional rewards.

Comment: Hmm...I'll have to think this over then. Shamshiel makes excellent points as well.

Comment: @TomSterkenburg - No need to rush- I would recommend that you wait until Shamshiel replies to my comment under his answer.  It is beyond any doubt that the Orcs received some sort of pay for certain tasks, at the very least.  What form that pay took, and how often they received it, I can't say.  I'm not an expert on Tolkien as so many people on this site seem to be.

Comment: @TomSterkenburg - according to the answer I accepted to [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89594/are-there-businesses-in-mordor) question, Tolkien never addressed the issue of Mordor's economy.  Many have speculated about it, however, and the answer contains links to four different articles on the subject.

Comment: @WadCheber: I think my answer is wrong and yours is right. :) I simply forgot the passage you quoted. I could add to your answer more information about how Sauron rewarded and punished based on the experience of early Men who followed Sauron, if you think  we can take them to be illustrative (vis a vis Orcs.)

Comment: "Getting payed by Sauron" doesn't only have to mean coins. It can also be a military title or a pool in the backyard.

Comment: @Trollwut - I never said they got cash.  They got a financial incentive of some kind - presumably loot, i.e., booty, plunder, stolen stuff.

Answer (score 7):

I don't believe there are any references to Orcs receiving a stipend from eihter Sauron or Saruman. But there isn't anything particularly problematic about this: soldiers in the real world haven't always historically been paid, and on top of that, Sauron (and presumably Saruman) was not considered merely a great King, or a leader, or a boss, but a *god*. It's probably a little much to expect that anyone would demand a bill from God for their work!

> Sauron desired to be a God-King, and was held to be this by his servants; if he had been victorious he would have demanded divine honour from all rational creatures and absolute temporal power over the whole world.

(Letters)

Again, remember that even historical armies haven't always been paid - and I don't mean that they were simply *not paid*, but that there was no expectation of being paid for performing your civic/divine/etc duty.

Certainly Orcs are provided with what supplies they need - the logistics don't work otherwise. But probably the only compensation they could hope for was whatever loot they ran across that Sauron wasn't interested in. Following the 'divine' direction of Sauron was probably also a more reliable way to get fed than the chaotic infighting that appears to be a constant in 'independent' Orc life.

And most likely, Orcs who accumulated too many nice things didn't live very long in the presence of other Orcs.

Comment: You may want to mention looting

Comment: I know of at least one reference to Orcs being paid for their services.  See my answer.

Comment: But in the only real glimpses of Orcish attitude we get , the orcs seem to look on Sauron as a boss - and a fallible one, at that.  They seem to be serving out of fear and desire for loot.  And, it must be admitted, a bit of self interest.  One of the captains puts it thus: "But don't forget: the enemies don't love us any more than they love Him, and if they get topsides on Him, we're done too. "

Comment: @jamesqf - yes, when Frodo and Sam are hiking through Mordor, they are relieved to see that Orcs are often too busy fighting amongst themselves to notice the hobbits in their midst, but wary of the fact that the Orcs hate everyone else more than they hate each other, and if they noticed the hobbits, they would instantly set aside their differences and murder the halflings.  Their attitude towards Sauron is based on fear, not love or true respect.  They follow his orders because they fear what he will do to them if they disobey, not because they are loyal to him.

Comment: I think you included a detail which I omitted - that an Orc with lots of nice stuff doesn't live very long.  :). At one point, Sam and Frodo are being hunted by a tracker Orc and a soldier Orc.  The tracker ends up shooting an arrow into the soldier's eye because he wants to go home but the soldier won't let him.  If "I'm bored, and I want to take a nap" is sufficient cause for him to kill his comrade, imagine what else they'll kill each other over.